# Getting error in JSONobject$1 in JSONObject

Tags: android, json

How to solve this error please suggest.

Getting error on Passing Coordinates in JSONObject. and mapbox markers gives null pointer exception error.

The response of API

```
[
    {
        "SrNumber": "45",
        "LatLng": {
            "H": 52.3743585,
            "L": 4.8904904
        },
        "Category": ",Apparel & Shoes,",
        "Detail": {
            "name": "United Nude | Amsterdam"
        },
        "location": "Amsterdam",
        "place_title": "United Nude | Amsterdam"
    }
]
```

JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest ( urlbase, new Response.Listener () {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    String img = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/retail-safari-new-app/";
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length (); i++) {

```
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject ( i );
                        String category = jsonObject.getString ( "Category" );
                        category = category.replace ( ",", "" );
                        String DetailsString = jsonObject.getString ( "Detail" );
                        JSONObject DetailsObj = new JSONObject ( DetailsString );
                        Title = DetailsObj.getString ( "name" );

                        JSONObject coordinateJsonObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("LatLng");
                      //  JSONObject coordinatesObj = new JSONObject ( coordinates );
                        lat = coordinateJsonObj.getDouble ( "H" );
                        lng = coordinateJsonObj.getDouble ( "L" );

                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng (coordinateJsonObj.getDouble ( "H" ),coordinateJsonObj.getDouble ( "L" ) );

                        IconFactory iconFactory = (IconFactory) IconFactory.getInstance ( MapActivity.this );
                        Icon icon = iconFactory.fromResource ( R.drawable.marker );

                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = (MarkerOptions) new MarkerOptions ()
                                .position ( latLng )
                                .title ( Title )
                                .snippet ( Address )
                                .icon ( icon );
                        mapboxMap.addMarker ( markerOptions );
                        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom ( latLng,  12);
                        mapboxMap.moveCamera ( cameraUpdate );
                        mapboxMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

                        Location locationA = new Location ( "point A" );

                        locationA.setLatitude ( locationlat );
                        locationA.setLongitude ( locationlng );


                        Location locationB = new Location ( "point B" );

                        locationB.setLatitude ( lat );
                        locationB.setLongitude ( lng );

                        float distance = locationA.distanceTo ( locationB );   // this gives distance in meters
                        distance = distance / 1000;
                        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat ( "#.##" );
                        distance = Float.valueOf ( decimalFormat.format ( distance * 0.621 ) );
                        String DistanceInMiles = String.valueOf ( distance );


                        DistanceInMiles = DistanceInMiles + " mi away";

                        MapActivityModel places = new MapActivityModel ();
                        places.setCategory ( category );
                        places.setTitle ( Title );
                         places.setLat ( lat );
                        places.setLng ( lng );

                        PlacesList.add ( places );

                        Collections.sort ( PlacesList, new Comparator<MapActivityModel>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(MapActivityModel t1, MapActivityModel t2) {
                                return new String ( t1.getDistance () ).compareTo ( t2.getDistance () );
                            }
                        } );


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace ();
                     //   progressDialog.dismiss ();
                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
          //      progressDialog.dismiss ();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener () {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e ( "Volley", error.toString () );
           //     progressDialog.dismiss ();

            }
        } );
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue ( this );
        requestQueue.add ( jsonArrayRequest );
```

```
error getting: W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value null at LatLng of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject
        at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:101)
        at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:616)
        at earthnew.retailtrendsinc.www.myapplication.MapActivity$5.onResponse(MapActivity.java:453)
        at earthnew.retailtrendsinc.www.myapplication.MapActivity$5.onResponse(MapActivity.java:429)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:83)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:106)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: please add code how you parsing JSONArray ?

Comment: @Bunny Please check now

Answer (score 0):

You are doing mistake in the parsing area. I assume that jsonObject is the object for the item from where lat lng will be fetched.

```
JSONObject coordinateJsonObj = jsonObject.getJsonObject("LatLng"); //Since LatLng is a json object.

lat = coordinateJsonObj.getDouble ( "H" );
lng = coordinateJsonObj.getDouble ( "L" );

LatLng latLng = new LatLng (lat, lng);

....Rest section
```

Comment: can you print the error and the code for entire class you have done?

Comment: yea i show the error in my question in end. and check the code now

Comment: Your exception is not in detail because it is not showing the line number where it is crashing. Please post the detail creash report.

Comment: Further there are so many places where you may get NullPointerException. Also instead of getString() from json, use optString(). It will avoid get get exception from the scenario where fields are not coming such as address, about, rating so on. And put null check when you are goint to make some operation over that such as "about".

Comment: so please just let me know what should I have to change in my code

Comment: As I have mentioned, I need the detail crash report to get the errornous area.

Comment: Updated now please check the Error

Comment: I think you are not getting different fields in your response all the time. May be few fields are missing in some of the cases. So you put null check when going to use any value. If you are more confused then use gson library where is will auto populate the model class from Json string.

Comment: You can get help for Volley using gson from https://kylewbanks.com/blog/tutorial-parsing-json-on-android-using-gson-and-volley.

Answer (score 0):

try to use like
`optJsonObject("LatLng")`, `optDouble("H")`
I think you got somewhere in JsonArray `null` in `"LatLng"` field so it is not able to converted to JsonObject.

So try to use parse data with example `jsonObject.optJsonObject("LatLng")`
Use `not null` condition also

Comment: I am not using retrofit.